# In RubyMine: "Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rubymine

I've created a ruby on rails project with rails composer. I can run the project from terminal, but when I open it in RubyMine, it's showing this error

```
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
```

I have checked my ruby version using 'ruby -v' and it says

```
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]
```

My rails version using 'rails -v'

```
Rails 3.2.13
```

However, when I open the project in RubyMine(version: 5.4.1) it says

```
/path/to/my/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:361:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
```

The SDK version in RubyMine is showing 'RVM: ruby-2.0.0-p195' and the language level is 1.9

I have checked other threads on this error, but none of them was working in terminal and showing error in RubyMine. How can I solve this?

Comment: Open you Gemfile and see if you have a ruby version over there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In RubyMine you can manage multiple SDKs, meaning ruby version and gemset.
Obviously you selected a SDK with ruby-2.0.0-p195.

The `language level` only defines the syntax higliting and command completion help etc. say the support of the IDE, but not the ruby version used for the project.

So you should select a different SDK (or create it first, but as you use `rmv` and RubyMine knows rmv, you should see all your SDKs)

If ruby-1.9.3 is your system default, you might install the same version again with rvm to make it available for RubyMine

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3
```

and then select it in RubyMine.